# how to display images images from internet in my android gridview and display full image?

Tags: android, image, gridview, swipe

how to display images from internet to gridview in android application.after display clicl om any image in gridview it will display full screen image after swipe left to right and right tp left.already i implemented some code, one error is there. after display fill image how to swipe those images.

**ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.img_2, R.drawable.img_3,
        R.drawable.img_4
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  
     imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
}
```

FullImage:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {


 private static final String LOGID = "CHECKTHISOUT";

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 160;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

     // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
}
private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                next();
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                previous();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void next()
    {

    }
    public void previous()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: ACtually what the error is showing in logcat??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show images in gridview and then you can use viewpager to display full-screen images with swipe.
I would suggest you to reuse the images rather than downloading them each time from internet.you can utilize the available libraries like https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader and it will handle the cache mechanism for you.